# Can an Metro Windows 8 C++ Application contain inline Assembler?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, inline-assembly, microsoft-metro

Can an Metro Windows 8 Application contain inline Assembler?
Also is Metro C++ Native, or managed, or can you mix them both like C++/CLI?

Comment: I don't see how it would be useful if you could. Are you going to write both x64 and ARM asm?

Comment: @ildjarn: Seems, that portability of his code is obviously not what he's looking for.

Comment: @ildjarn , just curious at this stage, but yes if i wanted to i'd have to , just like compiling binary to different targets, write conditional code for X64 and ARM. which isn't a big deal since in the past i wrote conditional Assembler for MMX, Amd 3dNow, SSE, SSE2, SSE3 etc all on the x86 platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Metro style apps use WinRT, which is COM-based replacement of an old WinAPI. You are able to create own WinRT components that can be used from .NET or even from JavaScript - and it costs you no extra effort. As for existing C++ code, note that only a subset of Win32 is provided in WinRT.

[image]

It doesn't matter whether you code in C/C++, C# or JS, when you use WinRT, you don't directly call the WinRT but it goes through a binding called **projection**, which is what takes care of your WinRT components to be exposed to the other language appropriately.

[image]

***"Can an Metro Windows 8 Application contain inline Assembler?"***
You are able *to embed assembly-language instructions directly in your C and C++* code because your compiler allows you to do that. Look at Inline Assembler as a set of assembly instructions written as inline functions, that are **built in the compiler**. The fact that you are using WinRT is irrelevant here.

Questions, that could help you:
[Why is WinRT unmanaged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7457371/1168156)
[C++, C# and JavaScript on WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7466303/1168156)
[What are WinRT language projections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7432905/1168156)

Comment: thanks. I know the APIs you can access from C++ are limited, i'm just wondering if you can do inline Assembler.. Like a simple ASM algoritm, that is self contained and doesn't call any APIS?

Comment: @klumsy: You are able to write Inline Assembler in your C and C++ code as long as your **compiler** allows you to do that. Check my answer now.

Comment: I don't know if it will pass WACK, however.

Comment: The WACK is a binary level static analysis tool. It doesn't analyze source.