# Python support for Windows 8

Tags: python, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8

Can we develop apps for Windows 8 or Windows RT in Python? If yes, then please tell me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432905/what-are-winrt-language-projections

Answer (score 1):

A Google search gave this result from PyCon 2013: [Windows 8 Apps and Python](https://us.pycon.org/2013/schedule/presentation/127/)